# Store html form input in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, forms

I am trying to store the inputs of the html form in a simple array.
I found some simple tutorials but my code is still not working, maybe I just can't see the fault.
This is how I made an array:

```
var person = [];
person[0] = $('#email').val();
person[1] = $('#password').val();
```

And this is my html, I have the span #demo, where I checked if there's a value in the array:

```
<input id="email" type="email" name="email" required="required"/><span id="errorfld"></span>
<input id="password" name="password1" type="password" required="required"/><span id="result"></span><span id="demo">text</span>
```

Then I have a function, which is called on focusout:

```
function demo(){
    $('#demo').text(person[0]);
}
```

Do I have to search my fault somewhere else?

Comment: When is that javascript code (in the first block) being called? If it's called when the page loads the text fields are still blank. You need to retrieve the values after the user types in them (in the blur function).

Comment: @Lenny It is called in document.ready

Comment: On document.ready the input fields are blank. You need to call it again later.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `$.serializeArray()` to get all the values from the form.

Example

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serializeArray();
    $('#demo').text(data[0].value);
});
```

**DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/7ysbd962/1/**

Answer (score 0):

If you just get the value when the page loads `document.ready` the input fields are still blank. You need to retrieve the values when you want to use them like this...

```
$(function(){


  function updateDemo(){
    var person = [];
    person[0] = $('#email').val();
    person[1] = $('#password').val();  

    $('#demo').text(JSON.stringify(person));
  }

  $('#email').on('blur',updateDemo);
  $('#password').on('blur',updateDemo);



});
```

Here is [an example](http://embed.plnkr.co/zhIuc9XipAs0B78axChM/preview)

You could also use a different listener like `keyup` to update the value every time the key is pressed.

[Another example](http://embed.plnkr.co/yHumtMMuVgxwpbJfhJHa/preview)